# Which pronoun to use with goûter?

Tags: pronoms

So *apparently* you can say:

> Il goûte la pomme.
>   Il goûte de la pomme.
>   Il goûte à la pomme.

Which is crazy.

So....am I supposed to say... *Je la goûte, j'en goûte,* or *j'y goûte*?

Or are they all correct, with minute variations in meaning?

Comment: Je trouvais les exemples avec *jambon* bien meilleurs. Peut-être parce qu'il est plus souvent utilisé en tant qu'indénombrable que *pomme*? Quand on a une pomme, on la mange et c'est tout :-)

Comment: Well...I changed it because "du jambon" might mean "some ham" and I wanted to be explicitly clear that the *de* was part of the *goûter* and not a partitive article. I tried making this comment in French and failed *miserably*, by the way.

Comment: But… it *is* a partitive article here :-)

Comment: Je l'ai changé car...*du jambon* peut utiliser l'article partitif, et je voulais éclaircir que je voulais dire *goûter de*, pas *du jambon*....oui?

Comment: Is it? I know little of such complex franco-linguistic matters...I thought it was like "to taste of the apple."

Comment: Literally, the partitive article in “du” or “de la” rather translate to *some*. To “taste some apple”. But again it sounds better with ham… or wine, etc. Masculine or feminine won't help to make a difference between partitive article or preposition. This prepositional *goûter de*… “taste of” is quite old I'd say. Which means you'll find it in literature works or in slang expressions (as noticed by cl-r) only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are all correct and correspond to the available variations on [*goûter*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/gouter).

- A direct transitive use of *goûter*: “goûter la pomme”, “**la** goûter”.
- A transitive use of *goûter* with the partitive article: “goûter de la confiture”, “**en** goûter”.
- Or *goûter à quelque chose*: “goûter à la brioche”, “**y** goûter”.

As per the TLF, *goûter de* where *de* is a preposition also exists. In the case of apples, it writes “goûter d'une pomme” (indefinite) or “goûter de la pomme” (definite), “goûter de pomme” (partitive). Uses like “goûter de literature” or “goûter de sa colère” are slightly more typical, but this variant completely faded away in modern non-literary French. The associated pronoun is always “**en**”.

Answer (score 3):

> Je goûte à la maison : je prends mon goûter à la maison

Il est plus habituel de *goûter un[e]* lorsqu'il n'y a qu'un fruit.

> *Je goûte une* pomme, donc, *je la goûte*. (le fruit en son entier).
>
> Voilà un beau rôti, *j'en goûterais* bien un morceau (une partie du plat).
>
> Demain nous irons à Saint-Émilion, j'y goûterai leurs vins (le lieu où je déguste).

*EDIT suite aux commentaires*

Je réserverais *goûter à* avec l'emploi d'un substantif :

> J'ai goûté au vin.

Ou alors entamer un fruit et ne pas le finir :

> *J'ai goûté à* la pomme, et je l'ai abandonnée sur la table.

Sinon pour préciser l'endroit où la degustation se fait :

> Nous allons *goûter* l'alcool *à la* sortie de l’alambic (lors d'une visite dans une distillerie).

Dans le domaine argotique

> "N'y reviens pas, ou je te ferai *goûter de ma* canne, chenapan" (Un vieillard qui menace de bastonner un petit voleur)

Comment: « Goûter à la pomme » (soit la même chose que « goûter au vin », « goûter aux bonbons ») est incorrect ? Tu contredis le TLF ? Peut-on savoir pourquoi ?

Comment: Même chose pour « goûter du vin », je ne vois pas ce que tu as contre l'usage du partitif ici. Certes l'exemple de la pomme sonne mal, mais il faut savoir généraliser un peu pour expliquer la grammaire.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Goûter à, "Boire, manger une certaine quantité de.". Les exemples cités concernent des substantifs ou des nourritures en quantité. L'expression "j'ai goûté à la pomme" me gêne car je ne peux alors m'empêcher de voir une pomme mordue et abandonnée, je préfère utiliser à dans l'expression "j'ai goûté à une des pommes offertes en dégustation". Mais comme *Eve a goûté à la pomme* … et qu'Adam l'a terminée, je modifie mes exemples. P.S. je suis beaucoup plus francophone que grammairien, et c'est parce que "cela sonne mal" que je voulais éviter de le donner en exemple.

Answer (score 2):

Il goûte la pomme.
définit

Il goûte aux plaisirs de la glisse. 
non définits

Il goûte de la pomme. 
"Il profite de la confiture de pomme" is possible but to speak of apple there isn't: he taste of its apple

Comment: You should make a proper account! Make good use of stackexchange, it's amazing!

Comment: nice to meet you.